# How can I make a USB stick I can boot from and fix this boot record error?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, boot

I don't have a Windows 7/Vista CD on me, and I don't know if Windows on this computer is windows vista/7.  it's a friend's computer.

It says:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD    

  Info: An error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.
```

I'd like to boot from a USB stick and fix that error.

I have a working Windows XP machine and a USB stick. And the problem computer can boot from USB.

Could anybody answer with instructions on how to go about this?

Comment: I have since told my friend to pass the machine to somebody else to fix since I lack the time and equipment to fix it at the moment. I'd have backed up his data too / cloned his drive, but just don't have what is needed to do it. If I had it i'd have tested some of these answers.  I will do but will be months, but one day when I get windows 7 and a new machine.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net). It comes with "Dual-boot Repair". 
Install in XP.

If you have an installed Windows 7/Vista on any partition "Dual boot Repair" -> "Automatic Repair" will fix Windows 7/Vista booting.

Later when in Vista/7 you can add entry for booting XP (if missing) using Visual BCD Editor -> rightClick and select "Create missing Windows loaders".

Everything is done on click automatically - no parameters, partitions or what ever to specify.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would go to www.pendrivelinux.com, download he YUMI bootable USB stick creator, then go to http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd, and get the zip file of Hiren's boot disc. Use that to make a bootable pen drive that will allow you to boot to Hiren's boot disc. I'm sorry I don't have exact instructions from there, but I know there is a way to repair boot records, plus a host of other utilities on that disc that will allow you to fix your problem. You should have no problem doing all of this from your Windows XP machine.

If you run into issues, post comments here and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Using second link mark provided you can install windows from a usb drive, you need to have an image of windows to copy to the usb after you format it to ntfs. the bootsect command in that tutorial is what makes the usb become a "bootable" drive. After that all you have to do is get into the bios and make sure you change boot priority to the given usb drive.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download

you don't need to created a Windows 7 USB drive, and you their is no documented way to do it without a Windows 7 DVD.

For Example: 
http://maketecheasier.com/boot-and-install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive/2009/01/23

Comment: How will this solve it? Could you edit and expand your answer more for a reason as to why downloading ubuntu will do a thing?

Comment: @SimonSheehan better than nothing! second link is bette than nothing at least.. and he doesn't have enough rep to post a comment

Comment: @barlop He can comment on his own posts.